# Apache camel - CXFRS: Handle input format exception

Tags: java, web-services, exception, apache-camel, cxfrs

I created a rest webservice with Apache Camel CXFRS and i want to control input format.

This is blueprint.xml:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://URL/" serviceClass="ngt.sas2sendsms.Getparams"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="GET_DLR">
        <from uri="cxfrs://bean://rsServer"/>
         <setBody>
                <simple>${body[0]} ${body[2]} ${body[1]}</simple>
        </setBody>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

This is Getparams.class

```
public class Getparams  {
    @GET
    @Path("rxstatus")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getAssets (@QueryParam("msgid") String msgid,  
                            @QueryParam("ts") int ts,
                            @QueryParam("status") int status
                            ) 
    {
     return null;
    }
}
```

when i run this route in browser over this URL: `http://url/rxstatus?msgid=3&status=test&ts=44443`

I get this message error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test"
```

it's normal beacause in status param i set a String instead an Integer. So i try to handle this exception.

i tried this:

```
 public class Getparams implements ExceptionMapper<NumberFormatException> {
            @GET
            @Path("rxstatus")
            @Produces("text/plain")
            public String getAssets(@QueryParam("msgid") String msgid,  
                                    @QueryParam("ts") int ts,
                                    @QueryParam("status") int status
                                    )
                    {
                     return null;
            }
  @Override 
  public Response toResponse(NumberFormatException arg0)
  {         
    return Response.serverError().build();
  }
}
```

But it i still get: `java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "test"`
How can i Handle it ?